# Перестала создаваться dbo.AspNetRoles

Tags: asp.net, mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Почему-то перестала создаваться dbo.AspNetRoles. Работаю в военно-полевых условиях, откатиться и сравнить возможности нет.

Что можно посмотреть хотя бы приблизительно, чтобы разобраться? Контекст вроде создается как раньше.

```
Ошибка сервера в приложении '/'.

Недопустимое имя объекта "dbo.AspNetRoles". 
 Описание: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода. 

Сведения об исключении: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Недопустимое имя объекта "dbo.AspNetRoles".

Ошибка источника: 



Строка 97:             foreach (string roleName in roles)
Строка 98:             {
Строка 99:                 var role = await Database.RoleManager.FindByNameAsync(roleName);
Строка 100:                if (role == null)
Строка 101:                {
```

Comment: Миграции включены?

Comment: нет. Я БД полностью удаляю через ssms, запускаю проект и он должен с чистого листа создать БД... В БД пока важных данных нет. Понимаю, что формулировку вопроса задал мутно очень, но сам не понимаю почему так вдруг произошло и не знаю куда копнуть даже.

Comment: Короче, вероятно какой-то баг был из-за конфликта двух контекстов. У меня 2 контекста,работающих с 1 БД были. Слил все в один контекст.